# How to prevent browser from caching URLs in which session used in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, caching

In my Codeigniter application when I logout and click back button of browser i can see previous page(page must be seen only after log in). When I log out and close browser tab.I can't go to previous page in anyway (for example visiting history). I think in first case browser caching URL. In Codeigniter how to prevent browser from caching URLs in which session used

Comment: Having your logout method end with a redirect to a new url will probably do the trick. Sending the user to the login page is my favorite way to handle it.

Comment: As @DFriend says. Also, check [here some useful contents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).